# Validar campo textarea com summernote e php

Tags: php, jquery, summernote

Estamos usando o summernote em um projeto com Bootstrap. Ele está dessa forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O HTML está dessa forma:

```
<textarea class="md-form-control md-static" id="summernote" name="Mensagem" rows="18" ></textarea>
```

O JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

              $('#summernote').summernote({
                toolbar: [
                       // [groupName, [list of button]]
                       ['style', ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'clear']],
                       ['font', ['superscript', 'subscript']],
                       ['fontsize', ['fontsize']],
                       ['color', ['color']],
                       ['para', ['ul', 'ol', 'paragraph']],
                       ['height', ['height']]
                     ],
                  height: 350,                 // set editor height
                  minHeight: null,             // set minimum height of editor
                  maxHeight: null,             // set maximum height of editor
                  placeholder: 'Digite sua mensagem aqui...',
                  focus: true               // set focus to editable area after initializing summernote
              });

              $('.inline-editor').summernote({
                  airMode: true
              });
```

A validação dos campos está em PHP, só que não estamos conseguindo validar o campo textarea. Já tentamos:

```
if(empty($mensagem)){
  // Mensagem de erro
}
```

Quando demos o `print_r()` na `$_POST`, aparece dessa forma:

```
Array ( [TipoEnvio] => [Titulo] => [Mensagem] =>


) 1
```

Já usei o `strip_tags($mensagem,'<br><p>');`, mas de nada adiantou. Segundo a [documentação](https://summernote.org/deep-dive/) do summernote:

> The editing area needs `<p><br></p>` for focus, even if the editor
>   content is empty. So Summernote supports this method for helping to
>   check if editor content is empty.

E sugerem usar:

```
if ($('#summernote').summernote('isEmpty')) {
  alert('editor content is empty');
}
```

Só que precisamos validar no PHP. Quando dou `strlen($mensagem)`, ele retorna como já tivesse 11 caracteres, mesmo sem ter digitado nada. Como posso resolver isso?

Comment: Já tentou usar `empty(trim($mensagem))`?

Comment: Olá bio. Já tentei usar essa combinação, mas também não funcionou. Se não tiver solução, terei que usar Jquery para validar, mas estamos dando preferência que seja no PHP.

Comment: Olá dvd. Alterei o post e incluí o HTML com o Jquery.

Comment: Vc tá pegando com `$_POST['Mensagem']`?

Comment: Sim. Da forma tradicional `$mensagem = $_POST["Mensagem"];`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use o método que indicado pela documentação do Summernote para verificar se está vazio e se for positivo, esvazie o `textarea` antes do submit:

```
if($('#summernote').summernote('isEmpty')){
   $('#summernote').val('');
}
```

Desta forma, se nada for digitado no editor, o valor será enviado vazio para o PHP.

Comment: Olá dvd. Atendeu sim. Desculpe, esqueci completamente de dar como aceito. Obrigado.